# Geocoding API failed to provide response if "#" is included in the address

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to get a response from Geocode API for an address(company name,street,zip,country)to fill latitude and longitude.My API request is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=BULTORFER DE AGUSTÍN JURADO,AV. PIO X 102+5730+Rio Tercero+AR&sensor=true&key=****************
```

1. Company Name : BULTORFER DE AGUSTÍN JURADO
2. Street : AV. PIO X #102
3. ZIP :5730
4. Town :Rio Tercero
5. Country : AR

The response for the above API GET request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
    <error_message>You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account</error_message>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

But if I removed # from the  **Street : AV. PIO X 102** the API works fine and give proper result.How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to url encode '#' into '%23'. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding